# Why and when to use a new anaconda environment? (One environment for everything? A new environment for every project?)

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

I have a little bit of experience using Anaconda and am about to transition to using it much more, for all of my Python data work.  Before embarking on this I have what feels like a simple question: **"when should I use a new environment?"**

I cannot find any good, practical advice on this on StackOverflow or elsewhere on the web.

I understand what environments are and their benefits and how, if I am working on a project that has a dependency on a specific version of a library that is different to e.g. the latest version of that library etc. etc. ... then virtual environments are the answer; but **I am looking for some advice as to how to practically approach their use in my day-to-day work on different data projects**.

Logically there appears to be (at least) two approaches:

1. Use one environment until you absolutely need a separate environment
   for a specific project
2. Use a new environment for every single project

I can see some pros and cons to each approach and am wondering if there is any best practice that can be shared.

If I should use just one environment until I need a second one, should I just use the default "root" environment and load all my required dependent libraries into that or is it best to start off with my own environment that is called something else?

An answer to this question ["why create new environment for install"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59479253/252223) by [@codeblooded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8568784/codeblooded) gives me some hints as to how to use and approach conda environments and suggests a third way,

3. Create new environments on an as-needs basis, projects do not "live" inside environments but  use environments at runtime, you will end up with as many different virtual environments as you need to run the projects that you regularly use on that machine, that may be just one environment or it may be more

Anyway, you can see that I am struggling to get my head around this, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: I use anaconda for 1. avoiding conflicting packages(versions) and keep them separate. 2. better version control of packages that I use, 3. Clean path to packages. 

I usually go by your first approach.

Comment: @AshlinJP Isn't the first approach _Use one environment until you absolutely need a separate environment for a specific project_ ?

Comment: @AMC yes. I tend to use another env iff there are conflicting packages or I need version control for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer that works with data scientists I would strongly recommend creating an environment for each project. The benefit of python environments is that the encapsulate the requirements of a project from all other python projects.

In the case above, if you were to use Python36 for 8 different projects it would be very easy to accidentally upgrade a package or install a conflicting package that breaks other projects without you realising it.

In the work you do it might not be a big deal, but given how easy it is to create a separate environment for each project the benefits outway the small time cost.

I can tell you that if any of the developers I work with was found to be using a single python environment for multiple development projects they would be instructed to stop doing that immediately.

Comment: _They would be instructed to stop doing that immediately_ Well, I'm glad I don't work for you! (:

They may be easy to set up, but they are expensive from a storage point of view. My average env directory is more than 1 gb - storage is actually _not_ that cheap (despite what people think) and using 1 gb for short term projects is not a sensible use of storage, im(v)ho

Comment: Sorry you don't have enough resources to follow best practices for python development :( Having to worry about 1gb envs sounds painful. Cost benefit of separate project envs in development work is a no brainer. I've actually not worked with a dev that's ever tried to use an env for multiple projects.

Comment: Worrying about 1 gb envs (in fact, some of my envs are > 5 gb) is probably more common than you might expect, particularly in non-commercial settings. I do share envs across multiple projects. I know the risks, and I'm happy with those risks. I wouldn't be happy with being told I couldn't share envs across projects under any circumstance

Answer (score 0):

So the question might be old but I would like to add to the discussion that creating a new conda environment for a new project does not occupy a lot of storage space if you use only packages that you've already used in previous projects (which would be the same as if you were sharing one environment over several projects).

The reason for this is that conda does not create a new instance of the package, if it is already installed. It rather uses a [Package Cache](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html) with already decompressed packages in `/pkgs`.

You can test the outcome like this (I just did it for the recommended ['sypder-env'](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html)):

```
conda create -c conda-forge -n spyder-env spyder numpy scipy pandas matplotlib sympy cython
```

This will create an environment for your spyder installation (~2.2 GB). Now we can clone this environment

```
# export package list
conda activate spyder-env
conda env export > environment.yml

# create new env
conda create -n test

# add packages from spyder-env to test env
conda env update --name test --file environment.yml
```

The file explorer might tell you that the new env occupies 2 GB

[(File explorer showing 2 GB for test env)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrseh.png)

When actually it just uses 350 MB since most of it are links

[(Disk Usage Analyzer showing 350 MB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UIkk.png)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I think I worked this one out for myself.  Seems kind of obvious now.

You do NOT need to create an environment for every project.

However if particular projects require particular versions of libraries, a particular version of Python etc then you can create a virtual environment to capture all of those dependencies.

To give an example,

- let's say you are working on a project that requires a library that has a dependency on a particular version of Python e.g. Python 3.6,
- and your base (root) environment is Python 3.7,
- you would create a new anaconda environment configured to use Python 3.6 (maybe call it "Python36")
- and you would install all the required libraries in that environment and you would use that environment when running that project.
- When you have another project that requires similar libraries, you may re-use your now existing Python 3.6 environment (named "Python36") to run this new project,
- you would not have to create a new Python 3.6 environment, in the same way that you would not have to install multiple instances of Python 3.6 in order to run multiple projects that required Python 3.6.

Comment: _You definitely do NOT want to create an environment for every project._ What is the reasoning for this?

Comment: I guess I could have phrased this better.   I have changed the wording of the answer to incorporate your implicit feedback @AMC.  Although if you can improve please by all means go ahead and edit / add.  You can probably tell that I am only just getting used to working with Anaconda and is beginning to make more sense but am by no means an expert.  I couldn't find too much guidance online to help develop any intuitions around use.